# I need a way to find the five of clubs from this php array

Tags: php

I need to find a way to reference the five of clubs using a nested associative array. Nothing I try seems to be working.

I've basically just tried the basic ways to access arrays within arrays, but it's different this time because of the funky => guy.

Here is the array I need to grab the five of clubs from:

```
$cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];
$deck_sorted = [
    'red' => [
            'heart' => $cards,
            'diamond' => $cards,
            'wild' => ['joker']
    ],
    'black' => [
            'spade' => $cards,
            'club' => $cards,
            'wild' => ['joker']
    ]
];
```

All I basically need it to do is say something like "blackclub5" or something like that.

Comment: Please don't include tags that are unrelated to your problem itself. I've removed the `atom-editor` tag, it's irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: It's great that you tried something! Would you be able to show us what code you have (that doesn't work)?

Answer (score 2):

To access the club's `5` all you need to do is work through the heirarchy; first you pick a colour by name, then you pick the suit by name. To get the face value, you need to pass through the index of the `$cards` array - the `5` card is at index `3`, so you can access it with:

```
echo $deck_sorted['black']['club'][3]; // 5
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/MgPpu)**.

If you want to output something like `blackclub5`, it depends on exactly *how* you are retrieving this 'additional' information, but you can make use of **[`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)** to retrieve the name of the array you are referencing:

```
echo array_keys($deck_sorted)[1]; // black
echo array_keys($deck_sorted['black'])[1]; // club
echo $deck_sorted['black']['club'][3]; // 5
```

This will concatenate, and give you `blackclub5`, as can be seen **[here](https://3v4l.org/kGNbU)**.

Comment: Nice answer. It might be worth suggesting supplying keys for the `$cards` array so you can just go `['black']['clubs']['5']` or `['black']['clubs']['jack']`.